# Remove/delete laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to discover the laravel for the first time I started with laravel 4.2 I just created a new project but by mistaking I write the comand line like this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {wamp/www/myProject} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

when I saw my `www` directory I found the project Phase is something like that `C:\wamp\www\{wamp\www\myProject}`

now I realized that creating the project command should be something like 
`composer create-project laravel/laravel myProject 4.2 --prefer-dist`

now can I solve this problem without deleting the project and recreate it again or should I delete and recreate project

and is it right to just go to my wampServer and delete the project manually or there is a special command to do so via the composer.

regards

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just delete the folder. Composer just facilitate to create a laravel project on your behalf with correct version and dependencies.

Comment: thanks for ur reply so it's safe to just delete the folder and create a new project, no records saved to the composer files or anywhere, because I saw the `Application key` I thought some records will be saved in other places

Comment: All the composer specific data is stored in project itself in composer.json file. It is a PHP dependency management tool similar to npm for node.js and pip for python and so on.

Comment: simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

I saw you received an answer. You accepted it.

But you know, that is not the actual solution.

Your Composer has its own `command` to help you deleting your needed one...

here it is:

```
rm -rf {{your project folder name}}
```

make sure that your composer opened in right folder  direction.

That is,

> When you are in your project folder, you can not delete it from here. you need to go outside of your current directory. This will only occur when you have opened your project in your IDE, doing works, and then you realise, you need to DELETE this project...

that means, you should make `cd ..` this command.

If this seems hard to understand, don't panic, just do

```
rm -rf {{your project folder name}}
```

Comment: Although easy way for most people might be manually deleting the directory but I like using script. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: that is how we fight...
Thank you for your appreciation

Comment: How is this a composer command? Looks like a normal delete command to delete the folder.

Comment: Yes it is a just a delete command.
The composer command is "composer remove Vendor/Package Name" but I didn't tried this...

Comment: hei that's no composer command that's just normal remove/delete command from terminal. That's same as deleting from graphical interface.